# How to mass produce reports with jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, loops, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook that produce a report. The report is a univariate analysis of a given variable of a big database (hundreds of variables millions of lines).

The structure of my notebook is as follow :

report.ipynb

```
read database
variable_of_interest = 'var1'
plots & html tables for 'var1'
```

I have been able to convert the notebook to a html file with nb convert from the console (but not from the notebook) and hide the code cells.

I would be interested in mass producing this report for all my variables : 'var1' ... 'varn'. I encouter some difficulties, mainly about building a loop that would change the variable of interest in a given notebook, then run it and convert it. (My first approach was to make the notebook update the variable name each time I execute it, but i still need some sort of loop to run it multiple time, and it is not very practical to handle specific variables).

To be more precise I need to :

- loop on all my variables names
- read the data once (or read only the variable in the loop ?)
- run the report for each variable (and produce plots & tables)
- convert the report to html with the name of 'report_vari.html', maybe in a specific folder 'report'
- continue running the loop in case of an error in one of the report

What would be the course of action to run this kind of loop, running a .py script from the console or another notebook ? What would it looks like ?

Comment: You should be able to pass parameters (3.g. your variable name) as an additional argument to nbconvert, then read the value with sys.argv. However this would require you to reload the data every time.
Another possible solution may be to use nbformal as library. Have a look at the code for notebooktoall for some clues on the API: https://github.com/notebooktoall/notebooktoall/blob/master/notebooktoall/transform.py

Comment: The code provided helped me to export the report.ipynb from another notebook. Not sure how to execute the notebook in each loop.

Answer (score 1):

[papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill) + nbconvert is the way to go. Papermill lets you parametrize notebooks, then you can convert them to HTML using nbconvert.

If you have complex dependencies among your notebooks, I recommend you to use [ploomber](https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber) (Disclaimer: I'm the author). It handles dependencies among tasks and transparently uses papermill and nbconvert to execute and convert notebooks.

Example:

```py
dag = DAG()

get_data = PythonCallable(_get_data,
                          product=File('raw.parquet'),
                          dag=dag)

clean_data = PythonCallable(_clean_data,
                            product=File('clean.parquet'),
                            dag=dag)

# execute notebook and convert to HTML
report = NotebookRunner(report,
                        product=File('report.html'),
                        dag=dag,
                        kernelspec_name='python3',
                        ext_in='py')

# run get_data, then clean_data, then generate report
get_data >> clean_data >> report
dag.build()
```

[Full example](https://ploomber.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auto_examples/reporting.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-reporting-py)